# Can't configure my If...else statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make statement like "if your product in belongs to category or you are in this category now, then category has different `<div>` tag".

I've tried some variants but I get this error:

```
<undefined method 'id' for #<Category::ActiveRecord_Relation:XXX>
```

This is the code from my aplication.html.erb:

```
<% category = Category.all %>
<% product  = Product.all %>

<% category.each do |category_c| %>
  <% if category_c.id == product.category.id or category_c.id == category.id then %>
    <div class="current">
      <%= link_to category.name, category %>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="category_link">
      <%= link_to category.name, category %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Unrelated, but `@category` and `@product` are mis-named. And shouldn't be instance variables.

Comment: You're calling `id` on all the categories, `@category`. The list of categories does not have an id.

Comment: Also, the repetition of identical DOM besides the style name should be abstracted away.

Comment: Use == instead of ===. === is used in case statements.

Comment: @Michal True(-ish), but not the issue.

Comment: I have applied all the changes but the error didn't gone.

Comment: @Mistthrt Unhelpful. First of all, don't keep editing the question with changes you're making. Second, if the error didn't go away, you're still calling `id` on a relation (e.g., all the categories).

Comment: I'm sorry, but what should I do to call `id` of category?

Comment: @Mistthrt Call it on a category, not all of them. You see where you have `category.id`? `category` (the mis-named collection of all categories) is all the categories. It doesn't have an `id` method.

Comment: The code actually makes much less sense with the following renames: `category` -> `categories`; `category_c` -> `category` and the error might even be spotted by the OP.

Comment: Ahh, can't understand. May somebody give me a link of good tutorial for theme?

Comment: @Mistthrt You have: `category = Category.all`. You later call `category.id`. But `category` is the result of `Category.all`. The complete list of categories doesn't have an id.

Comment: Okay, so I renamed `category` to `categories`. But I don't know how should I call just an item from db, not the complete list.

Comment: Give it an ID or a name or something and search on it?

Comment: I know. But what should I use instead of .all method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned - you are comparing a single id `category_c.id` to a set of categories - which doesn't work.

Now, for starters... it is good to get in the habit of naming *sets of things* in the plural... this will make this sort of error stand out more clearly next time. In which case your code should be adjusted to:

```
<% categories = Category.all %>
<% products  = Product.all %>

<% categories.each do |category_c| %>
  <%# note, this line will still break at this stage %>
  <% if category_c.id == product.category.id or category_c.id == categories.id then %>
    <div class="current">
      <%= link_to category_c.name, category_c %>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="category_link">
      <%= link_to category_c.name, category_c %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You might notice that you were *also* using the variable `category` (which was a set of categories) when trying to *display a link to the current category* which is wrong because you should be displaying a *single* category.

Naming the set of categories to be `categories` makes it more obvious when you are accidentally using a *set* when you mean a single one (and vice versa)... so stick to the habit.

If there is just one, use singular (eg category/product) if there is a set, use plural (eg categories/products)

---

Secondly - if what you want is to see if the product's category is in the set of categories... then you need to use a slightly different way of comparing:

```
if category_c.id == categories.id
```

breaks - because you are trying to call "id" on a set of categories... 
but a set of categories doesn't have a single id... 
only each category in the set has an id.

Instead try first fetching out the set of ids of the categories... then deciding if this category is *included* in that set

```
if categories.map(&:id).include?(category_c.id)
```

---

Thirdly... generally it's good to put the if/else only about the smallest part possible - only the part that changes depending on your conditions.

If you look at your if/else -  the link to the category and the div are the same, regardless of whether your condition is true or false. The only part that is different is the css-class that you are using in the div... so just put the if/else around that part like this:

```
<% categories = Category.all %>
<% products  = Product.all %>

<% categories.each do |category_c| %>
  <div class="<% if category_c.id == product.category.id or category_c.id == categories.id then %>current<% else %>category_link<% end %>">
    <%= link_to category_c.name, category_c %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Note: this has become a bit ugly... so lets put that condition into a variable and use that:

```
<% categories = Category.all %>
<% products  = Product.all %>

<% categories.each do |category_c| %>
  <% category_matches = category_c.id == product.category.id or category_c.id == categories.id %>
  <div class="<%= category_matches ? 'current' : 'category_link' %>">
    <%= link_to category_c.name, category_c %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

---

Fourthly.
Unless you know what the difference is... **always** use `&&` and `||` instead of `and` and `or` - you can study the difference later if you like... but even ruby professionals will use `&&` and `||` instead of `and` and `or` - so until you know why to use the other ones... just follow the standard practice so:

```
<% categories = Category.all %>
<% products  = Product.all %>

<% categories.each do |category_c| %>
  <% category_matches = category_c.id == product.category.id || category_c.id == categories.id %>
  <div class="<%= category_matches ? 'current' : 'category_link' %>">
    <%= link_to category_c.name, category_c %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

---

Now - I don't think we need the `categories` variable really... it isn't used again anywhere else... so just get rid of it.

```
<% products  = Product.all %>

<% Category.all.each do |category_c| %>
  <% category_matches = category_c.id == product.category.id || category_c.id == categories.id %>
  <div class="<%= category_matches ? 'current' : 'category_link' %>">
    <%= link_to category_c.name, category_c %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So the final thing is.... you have a set of products... but you're comparing against the id of a single product... 
I don't know how you get from a set of products to a singe product here - you aren't iterating over the set... you will have to have a think to figure out how you want to find *which* product is relevant to this code. I leave that as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 1):

So Your problem exists because you're calling `.id` on `category` which is a collection of all your `Category` models in your db because you assigned it as such here `<% category = Category.all %>`, no `id` would be associated with it.